# Accessing methods of extended class from inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes

```
public class ABC extends XYZ
{
          public static class InnerClass1
          {
            ...
          }
          public static class InnerClass2
          {
            ...
          }
          public static class InnerClass3
          {
            ...
          }
          public static class InnerClass4
          {
            ...
          }
}
```

In the above code, I cannot access the methods of the class XYZ inside the inner classes1,2,3 and 4. How can i modify the above structure so that the inner classes can access the methods within the class XYZ ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The methods you can't access, are they static methods?

Comment: Remember, static class can only access static members. So you cannot access any non static object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class ABC extends XYZ
{
      public static class InnerClass1
      {
        ...
      }
```

`InnerClass1` is not an inner class.  It's a *nested* class, because of the word `static`.

If there were no `static`, it would be an inner class.  And any instance of that inner class would have a hidden reference to an `ABC` (which is also an `XYZ`).  If the inner class called any instance methods of `ABC` or `XYZ`, or referred to any instance variables in those classes, it would use that hidden reference to call the instance methods or access the instance variables.

Since it's a nested class, though, there is no hidden reference to an `ABC` (or `XYZ`).  Thus, if you call an instance method or refer to an instance variable, it can't do it, because there is no `ABC` object to work with.  (However, you can still call a *static* method of an `ABC`, or refer to a static variable.)

I'm not sure what the solution is--it depends on your needs.  It's possible that the `XYZ` methods you can't call don't actually need an `XYZ` object to work on, and therefore those methods should be static.  It's also possible that the nested class should have some explicit `ABC` or `XYZ` variable that it uses to access the instance methods; you can still call instance methods from a nested class if you have an object to work on:

```
public static class NestedClass {
    XYZ x;
    void someMethod() { 
       x.instanceMethod();  // legal even if instanceMethod is non-static
    }
}
```

The other solution would be to remove the word `static`, so that `InnerClass1` really has a hidden reference to an `ABC`.  This means that when you create an `InnerClass1` instance, you need some `ABC` object for it to refer to.  If you create this in some other class, the syntax would be something like

```
ABC abcObject;
...
ABC.InnerClass1 newObject = abcObject.new InnerClass1();
```

Comment: Hi ajb, 
Thanks for your reply. I tried to implement the first solution you suggested. 

But, i'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException at the line x.instanceMethod();

Any solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian Make sure `x` is set to something that isn't `null`.  The actual answer is, figure out what you are trying to accomplish.  Does an instance of `InnerClass1` really "belong" to an `ABC`?  If so, the better solution is to get rid of `static`.  The thing is, you have to decide on what the classes actually mean and how they're related, and the answer will depend on that.

Answer (score 1):

static inner class can only access static members of the outer class

so the inner class will only be able to use the static members of xyz.

create the inner class non static if you want to access everything

Answer (score 1):

You have two options,  one remove the static call so a hidden this reference to the outer class is available to the inner class instances or two, when you create an instance of the inner class pass in a this explicitly, example:

```
public class ABC extends XYZ
{
     XYZ.InnerClass innerInst = new InnerClass(this);

          public static class InnerClass1
          {
            private final ABC extref;
            public void Innerclass(ABC outerref) 
            {
                extref = outerref;
            }

            ...
          }
}
```

Comment: "when you create an instance of the inner class pass in a this explicitly"   Could you please type how it could be done ?

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian See my example: in this case, the nested class has a variable `x` of type `XYZ` (it could be `ABC`).  So how would `x` get set?  Usually either with a setter, or with a parameter to the constructor, or some other way.  You'd have to figure out what works best for your application.

Comment: as ajb says, a setter or parameter on a constructor (I would prefer the constructor path as that is threadsafe way to set up the instance (setting in constructor assures no other usage of the object before its set (as the reference to the object is not normally known outside the object before the constructor returns (folks can violate that by taking the 'this' for the inner object instances and pass it out somewhere.