# How to access a method of Extended Class from nested class?

Tags: java, inheritance, nested-class

I have two nested classes inside a class with the outer class extending another class. The structure is something like this.

```
public class EXTENSION_CLASS
{
    public int Get_Value()
    {
        return(100);
    }
}

public class OUTER extends EXTENSION_CLASS
{
    public static class NESTED1
    {
        public void Method1()
        {
          int value=0;
          value=Get_Value();
          System.out.println("Method1: "+value);
        }
    }
    public static class NESTED2
    {
        NESTED1 Nested1_Instance=new NESTED1();
        public void Method2()
        {
            Nested1_Instance.Method1();
        }
    }
    public void run()
    {
        NESTED2 Nested2_Instance=new NESTED2();
        Nested2_Instance.Method2();
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
       OUTER New_Class=new OUTER();
       New_Class.run();
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the output: "Method1: 100". But, am getting the output: "OUTER.java:16: error: non-static method Get_Value() cannot be referenced from a static context value=Get_Value();". How can i make this working?

Cheers !

Rajesh.

Comment: Could you try with declaring Get_Value method also static?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question a couple days ago?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27339664/accessing-methods-of-extended-class-from-inner-class/27339698#27339698.

Comment: Is this question based on any real application, or are you just playing around to see what works and what doesn't in Java?  If it's a real application, I think we need to know more about what these classes are.  You've been given a number of solutions that will get the program to compile and output `100`, but not all of them would be appropriate in a real-life program.

Comment: You ***cannot*** be expecting the output: "Method1: 100" because you cannot be expecting anything from a program that does not compile. You are ***not*** getting the output: "OUTER.java:16: error: non-static method Get_Value() cannot be referenced from a static context value=Get_Value();" because this is not output, this is a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `static` modifier from the declaration of `NESTED1` and `NESTED2`, like so:

```
public class NESTED1
```

Comment: For some reasons, i don't want to remove the static modifier. Is there any other solution ? Thanks !

Comment: If you don't want to remove the static modifier, that means that a `NESTED1` isn't related to any `OUTER` or `EXTENSION_CLASS` object.  But if you're going to call `Get_Value`, you need some `OUTER` or `EXTENSION_CLASS` object for it to work on.  So you need to decide: what object are you trying to do `Get_Value` on?

Comment: See Roshith's answer - if you want access to an instance method from a static context, you must have an instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to make a `static` reference to a non-static member.

This means that you're trying to access a instance member from a static member of the class.

To fix the issue, remove the `static` modifier from both the NESTED1 and NESTED2 clases.

Alternately, if you do not wish to remove the `static` modifier, you will have to create an object of the `OUTER` or `EXTENSION_CLASS` classes and then invoke Get_Value() using the object.

For example:

```
public void Method1()
{
      int value=0;
      EXTENSION_CLASS ext = new EXTENSION_CLASS ();
      value=ext.Get_Value();
      System.out.println("Method1: "+value);
}
```

OR

```
public void Method1()
{
      int value=0;
      OUTER outer = new OUTER();
      value=outer.Get_Value();
      System.out.println("Method1: "+value);
}
```

Comment: For some reasons, i don't want to remove the static modifier. Is there any other solution ? Thanks !

Comment: Can you make the `EXTENSION_CLASS.Get_Value()` method `static`?

Comment: You can access the Get_Value() method `without` removing static by creating an object of the `OUTER` or `EXTENSION_CLASS` classes. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want keep the nested classes static, you will have to create an instance of OUTER in the Method1() to access  Get_Value().

```
  public void Method1()
    {
      int value=0;
       OUTER outer = new OUTER();
       value=outer.Get_Value();
      System.out.println("Method1: "+value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says every thing. You can not call non-static methods from static methods / class.
To make it work, Simply add static keyword to 'Get_Value' method in EXTENSION_CLASS.